# Azure Mobile Service and Javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure-mobile-services

Hi there i am stuck and somehow don't find the solution. It seems simple but, well ok. Here it goes. I have a mobile service in Azure and i want to reach that one with javascript. How do i get around the 401 Unauthorized? I tried with the documentation supplied from MS but no luck. This is what i got so far (adding the key to the url is not working of course) what can i add to get it to work?

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
"https://cdshop.azure-mobile.net/",
"vGpqzyApJXXXXXXXXblQCWne73"
);

var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function () {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
        callback(status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
};


$(function () {
$('#clickme').click(function () {

    getJSON('http://cdshop.azure-mobile.net/api/cds/total?key=vGpqzyApJXXXXXXXXblQCWne73', function (err, data) {
if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
} else {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
    result.innerText = data.result;
}
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your own HTTP requests, you need to set a request header called X-ZUMO-APPLICATION with your Application Key, e.g. "vGpqzyApJXXXXXXXXblQCWne73", for tables and APIs that are set to "application" or "users". (Assuming you are still using Mobile Services; the newer App Service does not use this X-ZUMO-APPLICATION header.) Tables and APIs set for "users" also need an X-ZUMO-AUTH request header with the user's authentication token.

Alternatively, you can use the MobileServiceClient you created in the first line, and it will do this for you. [This page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/) has examples for calling APIs and tables. For your example:

```
client.invokeApi("cds", {
    body: null,
    method: "get"
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
    result.innerText = data.result;
}, function(error) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + error);
});
```